# Is there any grails tag or plugin to accept international phone number

Tags: jquery-ui, grails, plugins, grails-plugin

I need to design or write one grails input field,which accepts international phone number(like what we see in gmail registration). I want the country field to be prelisted with country code, also need to validate entered phone number. Is there a grails ways of doing it, or is there any plugins available for this.

Comment: Have a look at [Grails Phonenumbers plugin](https://github.com/ataylor284/grails-phonenumbers). You can get most of the validation part for international numbers, format numbers and geolocate the number. I suppose you cannot use the same geolocator service to prepopulate the country code.

Comment: @dmahapatro thank you for your time, i 'll check

Comment: @dmahapatro is there any application, which already using this plugin

Comment: @dmahapatro sorry I think, I used a wrong keyword there, it is not phonenumber, it is  mobile number